# Convert Bound List to Generic List<T>

Tags: c#, list, generics, unity-container

I need to convert a bound (UnityEngine.Component) List to a generic (T) List, is this possible? how?

I'm using Unity and C#, but I would like to know in general how one would do this.

```
        List<Component> compList = new List<Component>();
        foreach(GameObject obj in objects)   // objects is List<GameObject>
        {
            var retrievedComp = obj.GetComponent(typeof(T));
            if(retrievedComp != null)
                compList.Add(retrievedComp);
        }

        List<T> newList = new List<T>(compList as IEnumerable<T>); // ERROR HERE

        foreach(T n in newList)
            Debug.Log(n);
```

thanks!

I assume that is the issue, I'm getting this runtime error...

```
ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: collection
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestPopulateClass].CheckCollection (IEnumerable`1 collection)
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestPopulateClass]..ctor (IEnumerable`1 collection)
DoPopulate.AddObjectsToList[TestPopulate] (System.Reflection.FieldInfo target) (at Assets/Editor/ListPopulate/DoPopulate.cs:201)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters)
DoPopulate.OnGUI () (at Assets/Editor/ListPopulate/DoPopulate.cs:150)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
```

Comment: Framework and language perhaps? Some code?

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: updated, but I'd like to know in general how this could be done in C#.

Comment: I get an error at List<T> newList = new List<T>(compList as IEnumerable<T>);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
    List<T> newList = compList.OfType<T>().Select(x=>x).ToList()
```

Comment: [OfType<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) and [Cast<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406) casts an object to T in the final projection.

Comment: but a normal cast using (T) wouldn't work? I'll need to read into it. My appreciation!

Comment: because there are some elements which are not of type T in the collection. Cast throws exception in such cases, OfType ignores them. Please refer to documentation link in 3rd comment for details.

Answer (score 0):

Most likley cased by the fact that T and Component are different types: `List<Component> compList` and `compList as IEnumerable<T>` (this one will be null since compList is `IEnumerable<Component>` not `IEnumerable<T>`).

I think you want:

```
    List<T> compList = new List<T>(); // +++ T instead of GameObject
    foreach(GameObject obj in objects)   // objects is List<GameObject> 
    { 
        // ++++ explict cast to T if GetComponent does not return T
        var retrievedComp = (T)obj.GetComponent(typeof(T)); 
        if(retrievedComp != null) 
            compList.Add(retrievedComp); 
    } 

    List<T> newList = new List<T>(compList as IEnumerable<T>); // ERROR HERE 

    foreach(T n in newList) 
        Debug.Log(n);
```

Comment: I get a few errors with this, 'Cannot convert type UnityEngine.Component to T for the cast'.  And 'Argument #1 cannot convert object expression to type T' at the Add

Comment: Tilak's answer (+1) contains correct implementation of code I was trying to maually fix. For manual implemetation to work correctly proper restriction on T should be set (likly `where T:Component`)...